# Qt: Prevent drag-and-drop on child widgets and show forbidden cursor

Tags: python, pyqt, drag-and-drop, pyqt5

I want to enable drag and drop functionality in some custom widgets, to allow reordering and rearranging the widgets within a layout. The basic functionality is working, but I'd like to prevent dropping a widget on itself, or on a child of itself. This is straightforward in the `dropEvent` method, but I can't find a way to also show the "forbidden" cursor while dragging, such that the user is aware that a drop will not be allowed.

The example below shows a test implementation, where the widgets "One" to "Five" can be dragged and dropped (no rearrangement will happen, only a message will be printed on the terminal, you may need to press Ctrl or something to initiate a drag). The problem line is the first `ev.accept()` in the `dragEnterEvent` method. By accepting the event, the cursor is shown in an "allowed" state (a grabbing hand for me). For example, trying to drag "One" and drop it onto "Three" appears as allowed, although nothing will happen. However, ignoring the event results in the event being propagated to the parent, so in that case dragging "Three" and dropping it onto "Three" results in "One" getting the drop instead. Setting the `WA_NoMousePropagation` attribute does not seem to make any difference.

So, what I would need is a way to "accept" the event, so that it will not be propagated to the parent, but still show a "forbidden" cursor, as if nobody accepted the event. Any ideas?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *


class WidgetMimeData(QtCore.QMimeData):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
      self.itemObject = None

    def hasFormat(self, mime):
        if (self.itemObject and (mime == 'widgetitem')):
            return True
        return super().hasFormat(mime)

    def setItem(self, obj):
        self.itemObject = obj

    def item(self):
        return self.itemObject


class DraggableWidget(QGroupBox):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)

    def addWidget(self, widget):
        return self.layout().addWidget(widget)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, ev):
        pixmap = QPixmap(self.size())
        pixmap.fill(QtCore.Qt.transparent)
        painter = QPainter()
        painter.begin(pixmap)
        painter.setOpacity(0.8)
        painter.drawPixmap(0, 0, self.grab())
        painter.end()
        drag = QDrag(self)
        mimedata = WidgetMimeData()
        mimedata.setItem(self)
        drag.setMimeData(mimedata)
        drag.setPixmap(pixmap)
        drag.setHotSpot(ev.pos())
        drag.exec_(QtCore.Qt.MoveAction)

    def dragEnterEvent(self, ev):
        item = ev.mimeData().item()
        if item.isAncestorOf(self):
          #ev.ignore()
          ev.accept()
        else:
          ev.accept()

    def dropEvent(self, ev):
        item = ev.mimeData().item()
        if not item.isAncestorOf(self):
          print('dropped on', self.layout().itemAt(0).widget().text())
        ev.accept()


class HelloWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        w1 = DraggableWidget()
        w1.addWidget(QLabel('One'))
        w2 = DraggableWidget()
        w2.addWidget(QLabel('Two'))
        w3 = DraggableWidget()
        w3.addWidget(QLabel('Three'))
        w4 = DraggableWidget()
        w4.addWidget(QLabel('Four'))
        w5 = DraggableWidget()
        w5.addWidget(QLabel('Five'))

        w1.addWidget(w3)
        w1.addWidget(w4)
        w2.addWidget(w5)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(w1)
        layout.addWidget(w2)
        layout.addStretch(1)

        centralWidget = QWidget(self)          
        centralWidget.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)   


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWin = HelloWindow()
    mainWin.show()
    sys.exit( app.exec_() )
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest way is to always accept the event in `dragEnterEvent` and in `dragMoveEvent` ignore it when the source of the event is an ancestor of `self`, i.e.

```
def dragEnterEvent(self, ev):
    ev.accept()

def dragMoveEvent(self, ev):
    item = ev.source()
    if item.isAncestorOf(self):
        ev.ignore()
```

By ignoring the event in `dragMoveEvent` you wouldn't need the check in `dropEvent` either and can simply do

```
def dropEvent(self, ev):
    print('Dropped of', self.layout().itemAt(0).widget().text())
    ev.accept()
```

Comment: Almost there, but it looks like `dragMoveEvent` is only executed if the mouse is moved *after* `dragEnterEvent`, I mean that it is possible to drop on a child widget if the mouse is stopped just when the child is entered (and the hand cursor appears). Keeping the check in `dropEvent` prevents the drop, but the hand cursor will still flash briefly when entering a child widget. Better than nothing, though.